# OS linux ubuntu is killing my mongod service

Tags: ubuntu, services, kill, database, mongodb

I am facing this issue consistently, whenever I run some CPU and memory intensive processes so OS kills my mongod service. Due to which service goes into the failed state and everything stops.

> Command:

```
journalctl -u mongod.service
```

> Output:

```
Jun 01 04:41:18 leadsearch systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Jun 01 04:41:18 leadsearch systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Is there any way to check details why my mongod service is being killed by OS?

Please suggested if there is anyway to fix this issue, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It sounds like your system is running out of RAM. Have you checked how much RAM you have available when this happens?

Comment: This is a long running job, how can i monitor RAM all the time?

Comment: Well, you can just keep an eye on it and see if it rises just before the service is killed. Alternatively, you can run `while :; do date; free; sleep 10s; done > ramlog` which will run `free` every 10 seconds. That should give you an idea of what is happening. Just leave that running and, next time the service dies, kill the while loop and check the `ramlog` file. That should help. But you already said this happens when you run memory-intensive processes, so it really sounds typical of the [OOM killer](https://docs.memset.com/other/linux-s-oom-process-killer).

Comment: What does the `mongod` log say?

Comment: I think i got it: mongod logs: failed to write 8192 bytes at offset 11183755264: No space left on device

Comment: @terdon That really had helpful, can we log CPU and disk usage as well along with RAM?

Comment: @AbdulMoiz yes, but that should be a separate question so you can explain exactly what you need. There are various tools designed for this anyway, it would be better to ask a new question.